# Can't deploy a privatelink service with Terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

Working on a Terraform script to deploy a Private Link Service.
This a part of my script:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "RG6"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.5.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                                      = "example-subnet"
  resource_group_name                       = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name                      = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes                          = ["10.5.1.0/24"]
  private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled = false
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "example-api"
  sku                 = "Standard"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "example" {
  name                = "example-lb"
  sku                 = "Standard"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = azurerm_public_ip.example.name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_link_service" "example" {
  name                                        = "example-privatelink"
  location                                    = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name                         = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  load_balancer_frontend_ip_configuration_ids = [azurerm_lb.example.frontend_ip_configuration[0].id]
  auto_approval_subscription_ids              = [local.subscription_id]
  visibility_subscription_ids                 = [local.subscription_id]

  nat_ip_configuration {
    name               = "primary"
    subnet_id          = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    primary            = true
    private_ip_address = "10.5.1.17"
  }

  nat_ip_configuration {
    name                       = "secondary"
    private_ip_address         = "10.5.1.18"
    private_ip_address_version = "IPv4"
    subnet_id                  = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    primary                    = false
  }
}
```

At run I get this error message:

> │ Error: creating Private Link Service: (Name "example-privatelink" /
> Resource Group "RG6"):
> network.PrivateLinkServicesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending
> request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error:
> Code="PrivateLinkServiceCannotBeCreatedInSubnetThatHasNetworkPoliciesEnabled"
> Message="Private link service
> /subscriptions/XXXXXXX/resourceGroups/RG6/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateLinkServices/example-privatelink
> cannot be created in a subnet
> /subscriptions/XXXXXXX/resourceGroups/RG6/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/example-vnet/subnets/example-subnet
> since it has private link service network policies enabled."
> Details=[] │ │   with azurerm_private_link_service.example, │   on
> config.tf line 83, in resource "azurerm_private_link_service"
> "example": │   83: resource "azurerm_private_link_service" "example" {

**My question**

Why I get this message. I set this parameter **false** :

```
private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled = false
```

This is asked from doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-link-faq

I tested for **true** just to check, same result.

This example is inspired from the doc:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/private_link_service

Comment: You're setting `private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled ` but you're creating a private link. Set `private_link_service_network_policies_enabled`and it should work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't deploy a privatelink service with Terraform

I do agree with <kbd>fredrik</kbd> for suggesting the same point.

The error you are encountered that **subnet** has `private link service network policies enabled`, which is preventing the creation of the **private link service**.

To resolve the issue, you should **disable** the private link service network policies for the subnet by setting the `private_link_service_network_policies_enabled = false` within the subnet module.

```kotlin
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name     = "RG7"
      location = "West Europe"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
      name                = "example-vnet"
      address_space       = ["10.5.0.0/16"]
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
      name                                      = "example-subnet"
      resource_group_name                       = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      virtual_network_name                      = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
      address_prefixes                          = ["10.5.1.0/24"]
      private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled = false
      private_link_service_network_policies_enabled = false
    }
    
    
    resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
      name                = "example-api"
      sku                 = "Standard"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      allocation_method   = "Static"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_lb" "example" {
      name                = "example-lb"
      sku                 = "Standard"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    
      frontend_ip_configuration {
        name                 = azurerm_public_ip.example.name
        public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
      }
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_private_link_service" "example" {
      name                                        = "example-privatelink"
      location                                    = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name                         = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      load_balancer_frontend_ip_configuration_ids = [azurerm_lb.example.frontend_ip_configuration[0].id]
      auto_approval_subscription_ids              = ["b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-2b83a074c23f"]
      visibility_subscription_ids                 = ["b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-2b83a074c23f"]
    
      nat_ip_configuration {
        name               = "primary"
        subnet_id          = azurerm_subnet.example.id
        primary            = true
        private_ip_address = "10.5.1.17"
      }
    
      nat_ip_configuration {
        name                       = "secondary"
        private_ip_address         = "10.5.1.18"
        private_ip_address_version = "IPv4"
        subnet_id                  = azurerm_subnet.example.id
        primary                    = false
      }
    }
```

**Terraform apply** result, without using the `private_link_service_network_policies_enabled = false` in the subnet module.

[image]

**Terraform apply** result, after setting `private_link_service_network_policies_enabled = false` in the subnet module

[image]

Reference:  [azurerm_subnet](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subnet)